# Update com relacionamento hasMany para dois inputs ao mesmo tempo no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Bom o problema que acontece é o seguinte, tenho em minha aplicação o campo telefone que se faz presente em um relacionamento para pessoaFisica então uma pessoa tem um relacionamento hasMany para telefones e esse por sua vez tem um belongsto para pessoa bom até ai tudo bem o problema está acontecendo quando vou fazer a alteração visto que são dois inputs, o código da view ficou assim:

```
 @foreach($pessoaFisica->telefones as $tel)
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   <label for="telefone" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Telefone:</label>
   <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="numero[]" id="numero"
   placeholder="Telefone - obrigatório"
   value="{{isset($tel->numero) ? $tel->numero : null}}">
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

isso se dá uma lista de telefones da seguinte forma:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e agora estou tentando pegar os dois campos para editar na tabela, e estou tentando fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
 $dados = $request->input('numero');
 $this->telefone->where('id_pessoa', $idPessoa)->update($dados);
```

mas está acontecendo um erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
sei que isso está se dando por se tratar de uma lista mas não sei como inserir ela em massa de uma vez ou de outra forma.

Answer (score -1):

O método update espera um array associativo como parametro. De uma olhada na documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#basic-updates

Sendo assim o método correto de efetuar o update é:

```
$dados = $request->only('numero'); // array ['numero' => '(number)']
$this->telefone->where('id_pessoa', $idPessoa)->update($dados);
```

Lembrando que para criar e update em massa é preciso definir no model.

> You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single
>   line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the
>   method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a
>   fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models
>   protect against mass-assignment.

Comment: Mas no caso o only não pegaria apenas o primeiro registro?

Comment: @AndréMartins leia a documentação. Only é método do request, onde você definir que ele irá retornar um array associativo apenas com os inputs que você definir. Leia documentação, procure por: Mass assign, Input Request e Eloquent Update